# C - X11 API: Graphics not Working in a While Loop

Tags: c, graphics, x11, xlib

I am trying to draw a background dynamically. The graphics work great normally...but:

```
int width, height;
GC gc_backcolor;
XGCValues gcv_backcolor;

width = c_values.width;
height = c_values.height;

gcv_backcolor.background = c_values.backcolor;
gcv_backcolor.foreground = c_values.backcolor;
gc_backcolor = XCreateGC(display, canvas, GCBackground | GCForeground, &gcv_backcolor);

int x = 0;
int y = 0;

while (y < height) {
    x = 0;

    while (x < width) {
        XDrawPoint(display, canvas, gc_backcolor, x, y);
        x++;
    }
    y++;
}

x = 0;
y = 0;
```

...for some reason, when I run it in a loop, it will not work. If anyone could explain to me why it is behaving this way, I would be grateful.

Could it be that I am calling this function on the canvas expose event?

```
  while(1) {
      XNextEvent(display, &event);

      if (event.xany.window == canvas) {
          if (event.type == Expose) {
              Canvas_Draw(display, canvas, c_values);
          }

       }
   }
```

Here is my main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include "Canvas.h"
#include "Extensions.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   Display* display;
   int screen;
   Window window;
   Window canvas;
   XEvent event;
   GC gc_canvas;

   //Canvas* canvas;

   display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

   if (display == NULL) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error trying to open display\n");
      exit(1);
   }

   screen = DefaultScreen(display);
   window = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screen), 0, 0, 640, 480, 1, BlackPixel(display, screen), WhitePixel(display, screen));

   XSelectInput(display, window, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
   XMapWindow(display, window);

   /*   Create Canvas   */

   XGCValues gcv_canvas;
   CanvasValues c_values;

   gcv_canvas.foreground = 0xff00ff;
   gcv_canvas.background = 0xff00ff;

   canvas = XCreateSimpleWindow(display, window, 0, 0, 256, 256, 1, BlackPixel(display, screen), WhitePixel(display, screen));

   gc_canvas = XCreateGC(display, canvas, GCForeground | GCBackground, &gcv_canvas);

   XSelectInput(display, canvas, ExposureMask | KeyPressMask);
   XMapWindow(display, canvas);

   Canvas_Create_Content_Field(display, canvas, c_values);

   c_values.backcolor = 0x00ff00;

   //Canvas_Draw(display, canvas, c_values); this code only appears to work in the expose event

   /*   Create Canvas   */

   while(1) {
      XNextEvent(display, &event);

      if (event.xany.window == canvas) {
      if (event.type == Expose) {
          Canvas_Draw(display, canvas, c_values);
      }

       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry...it had nothing to do with the graphics, but the width and height integers were set to 0 due to an error in a function I made and used in the function that creates the data array for the image:

```
int width, height;
width = Window_Get_Width(display, canvas);  // Window_Get_Width had some errors and
height = Window_Get_Height(display, canvas);  // Window_Get_Height had the exact same errors

c_values->width = width;
c_values->height = height;

int field[width*height];

c_values->field = field;
```

I fixed the errors, and now everything is working out great! :D

Answer (score 1):

You have not reset `x` within the outer `y` loop. Try this

```
while (y < height) {
    x = 0;                  // <<--- insert here
    while (x < width) {
        XDrawPoint(display, canvas, gc_backcolor, x, y);
        x++;
    }
    y++;
}
```

**UPDATE**

You are also setting the foreground and background to the same colour

```
gcv_backcolor.background = c_values.backcolor;
gcv_backcolor.foreground = c_values.backcolor;
```

and the background colour returned is being used to draw with

```
gc_backcolor = XCreateGC(display, canvas, GCBackground | GCForeground, &gcv_backcolor);
...
XDrawPoint(display, canvas, gc_backcolor, x, y);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that error, but it still refuses to draw anything. I will update my code for you.

Comment: Perhaps you are drawing with the colour that is already the background so you don't see anything.

Comment: No, I am using an integer value of 0x00ff00, Lime Green. The default canvas background is white. I tested it outside of the loop, and it works.

Comment: Yes, I am using them both, however, I use the same exact code minus the loop and it draws a single lime green pixel at my given position.

Comment: Did you intend to set `gcv_backcolor.foreground = c_values.backcolor;`?

Comment: Yes, I intended the same colour for both, it was a fix to previous issues I ran into...

Comment: I have to sleep now, but I will return tomorrow to read anything else on this topic.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't fix previous issues at all.

Answer (score 1):

For better performance, Xlib functions like `XDrawPoint` do not send the command to the X server immediately, but add it to the Xlib request buffer.  Xlib will send the contents of the request buffer to the X server when one of several things happens:

- Client calls [`XFlush()`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Handling_the_Output_Buffer) to flush the request buffer and send it all to the server.
- Client calls [`XSync()`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Handling_the_Output_Buffer) to flush the request buffer and send it all to the server, and then wait until the server responds that it has handled all the requests.
- The request buffer fills and Xlib flushes the current contents to make room for new requests.
- Client calls a function that requires a response from the server - Xlib flushes all the requests to be able to send the one needing a response.
- Client calls a event handling function such as [`XPending()`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Event_Queue_Management), [`XNextEvent()`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Returning_the_Next_Event), or [`XWindowEvent()`](http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/libX11/libX11.html#Selecting_Events_Using_a_Window_or_Event_Mask), and the client finds no events in the queue to handle, so flushes the buffer to give the server something to do that might generate an event.

In your case, you don't want the overhead of sending every single pixel in a separate packet to the X server, so you probably want to put an `XFlush()` call after your `while (y < height) { ... }` loop to send all the pixels at once then.